# Script to change hostname on CentOS

Tags: perl, hostname

I using `curl` to pull a hostname from a server using a HTTP get request, and that is working fine. I need my script to modify the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file so I don't have to restart the system to apply the hostname.

Here is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Sys::Hostname;


my $curl = `curl http://100.10.10.10/hostname`; # Get correct hostname 
my $host = hostname;

if ($curl ne $host) {
   # Need to modify the /etc/sysconfig/network file to replace hostname or add it.
}
```

EDIT:
My Actual Question: What is the best way for me to modify that file with the new hostname?

Comment: Don't forget to `chomp($curl);`

Comment: Well, you should lock the file, create a new file on the same volume, For each line in the original file { read from the original file, transform what you read as desired, write the changes to the new file }, then rename the new file over the original file.

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or are you looking for a code writing service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want is

```
my $host = qx{hostname};
```

instead of

```
my $host = hostname;
```

also, why dont you just make the changes manually (i.e, open /etc/hosts or whatever file you want to edit, and edit, just make sure the `$>` is 0... script is running as user root).

Comment: I am using "use Sys::Hostname;"